# ipdb requires Ctrl+D for processing command

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

I am debugging my Python scripts with ipdb. Somehow I have the problem, that after entering a command, for instance `n, s, c, b` etc. I have to press <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> two times in order for ipdb to process the command and proceed.

Any idea what causes this and **how I can turn it off**?

Comment: @EricLeschinski Yes, I see that. Although I guess it does not solve my problem, does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This effect is not isolated to ipdb:**

Technically Ctrl-D terminates transmission, and only raises EOF if this results
in an empty input buffer.  Which only happens when you press Ctrl-D before inputting any
characters.

Do this experiment:

```
1.  At the linux terminal type cat
2.  press enter once.
3.  enter letters: foo
4.  press <Ctrl-D> once, you don't get back to the terminal.
5.  press <Ctrl-D> again, you are brought back to the terminal.
```

So it looks like this:

```
user@defiant ~ $ cat
foofoouser@defiant ~ $
```

foo is printed twice because the first time you pressed  it flushed your input.  The second time it's interpreted as end the program.

**How to stop this behavior:**

Don't be connected to a TTY when you are pressing Ctrl-D.  Which means don't use a normal linux terminal.  Not sure if this is even possible.

**How to process a command in ipdb**

Pressing enter should process the command as illustrated by the video here:  http://www.gregaker.net/2012/apr/05/debugging-python-with-pdb-or-ipdb/

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean I should't be connected to a TTY? I start debugging on two ways: (1) in console I enter `ipdb myscript.py` and (2) add `import ipdb; pdb.set_trace()` to my script and run `python myscript.py`

Answer (score 1):

This is the thing: `Ctrl+D` does not kill programs, it cuts waiting halfway through. When you press `Ctrl+D`, you interrupt the process' `read()` call that's waiting for input.

## Ctrl+D

Most programs will abort when they read `0` bytes as input. If you `Ctrl+D` before entering anything, you'll be sending 0 bytes down the input pipe, and possibly **induce** a shutdown of a the program, which may think there is nothing left to be done. This is not **forced**.

However, if you press some keys, then `Ctrl+D`, the `read()` call you interrupted will return that text, and the underlying program decides to wait for another round.

That's why, when you `Ctrl+D` again without entering any new text, you get the behavior you expect.

## Your case

This is what's probably happening:

1. You type some character, they get buffered.
2. You `Ctrl+D`. The text reaches `iPdb`, but it does not detect a newline, and thus it waits for more.
3. You `Ctrl+D` again. This time `0` bytes reach `iPdb`, which assumes nothing more is coming and processes the text with or without newlines.

Comment: That should be the default behavior. Are you on Windows? Is there a misconfiguration on your keyboard/terminal? Maybe you're sending the wrong character when pressing enter?

Comment: No, I am on Ubuntu 12.04. I could imagine, that there is a misbehavior due to using Ubuntu as VM on Mac OS X.

Comment: Long shot: try the Keyboard Layout configuration, advanced options